# Can I make configuration required in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my startup code:

```
services.Configure<FooBarOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("FooBarOptions"));
```

The was a mistake, as I wanted

```
services.Configure<FooBarOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("FooBar"));
```

Obviously the typo cause the configuration to not be loaded. Is there a way to trigger an error during startup when a required config section doesn't exist?

Comment: I think simply check `Configuration.GetSection("FooBar")` is `null` or `empty` throw exception in startup.

Comment: Set up a postconfigure callback and check if the options is actually configured.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `PostConfigure<T>` with a callback which will run after every `Configure<T>` is executed. This will allow the user to configure an option in any way in any order, and let you go over the (un)configured options and throw an exception if needed.

```cs
class FooBarOptions
{
    public string AString { get; set; }
}

services.PostConfigure<FooBarOptions>(options => {
    // ... validate configuration
    if (options.AString == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidProgramException($"{nameof(FooBarOptions)} is not configured properly");
    }
});

services.Configure<FooBarOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("FooBarOptions"));
```

### References

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0#options-post-configuration
- https://andrewlock.net/delaying-strongly-typed-options-configuration-using-postconfigure-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thank you! The article in andrewlock.net is great!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var exist = Configuration.GetSection("FooBar").Exist();
if (exist) services.Configure<FooBarOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("FooBar"));
else ....throw exception
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the "binding" part of your Startup file a bit concise, an extension method on either `IConfiguration` or `IServiceCollection` would work. Here's a basic implementation.

```cs
static class ConfigurationBindingExtensions
{
    public static void BindSection<T>(this IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection services, string sectionName) where T : class
    {
        var config = configuration.GetSection(sectionName);
        if (config.Exists())
        {
            services.Configure<T>(config);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ConfigurationSectionNotFoundException(sectionName);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
[Serializable]
class ConfigurationSectionNotFoundException : Exception, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
{
    public string SectionName { get; set; }

    public ConfigurationSectionNotFoundException(string sectionName)
        : this(sectionName, string.Format("Section {0} was not found in the configuration file", sectionName))
    {
        this.SectionName = sectionName;
    }

    public ConfigurationSectionNotFoundException(string sectionName, string message)
        : base(message)
    {
        this.SectionName = sectionName;
    }

    protected ConfigurationSectionNotFoundException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(info));

        SectionName = info.GetString("SectionName");
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public override void GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(info));

        info.AddValue("SectionName", SectionName);

        base.GetObjectData(info, context);
    }

    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable.GetObjectData(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (info == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(info));

        GetObjectData(info, context);
    }
}
```

You would then call it like so:

```cs
Configuration.BindSection<FooBarOptions>(services, "FooBar");
```

This will throw a custom exception if the section is not defined - you can replace that with something else if it makes more sense to you. Probably overkill, but it keeps Startup.cs nice and tidy.